# Why does "print (int('100',2))" give output of 4 in python?

Tags: python

Hello I was trying to solve some code and I am stuck in this, I don't have any idea why `print(int('100',2))` outputs 4, please explain it to me.

Answer (score 3):

100 in binary system is 1*2^2 *0*2^1 + 0 = 4

Answer (score 3):

When you call `int()`, you are giving it two parameters: `'100'`, and `2`. The first parameter it takes is the number as a string, and the second is the base. So, you are telling it to convert the string `'100'` into an integer of base 2. 100 in base 2 is four, so you are getting this output. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The `int()` function converts the specified value into an integer number.

```
int(x, base=10)
```

`base` is optional and is set default to 10.

100 (in base 2, i.e. binary) is 4 (in base 10, i.e. decimal)

Answer (score 0):

The [int(x,base) function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int) converts a number from a specified base to a decimal integer. 100 in base 2 is 4 in base 10.

Similarly, if you run `print(int('10'),2))`, you will get `2`, since `10` in binary is equal to `2` in decimal.